# Add HTML code inside of a JS var that contains an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I need to add a list of task after to click one row in a html table I'm using knockout js. the problem is that I'm just adding de last task from my *data* in a row and I need to add a new TR inside my element *"$taskSelected"* for each task. Here is my code

```
  self.retrieveTask = function(data, event) {
                if (event.type=="click") {
                    var id = data.Id;
                    var $taskSelected = event.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
                    $.get("@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")", { id: id })
                        .done(function(data) {
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                var html = "<tr><td>" +
                                    "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" +
                                    "  <div >" +
                                    + value.Type +
                                    "</div> " +
                                    "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" +
                                    " <div >" +
                                    value.Id +
                                    "</div> " +
                                    "</td>" +
                                   "</tr>";
                                $taskSelected.innerHTML=html;

                            });

                        }).fail(function() {
                            alert("error");
                        });
                };

            }
```

the var $taskSelected contains  another row "*`<tr> </tr>`*"  basically Ii want to nested rows. Some advises please

Comment: You can't nest [rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) : "Permitted content: _Zero or more <td> or <th> elements, or a mix of them_". If you try to create a nested row, the opening tag of a "child" row will close the "parent" row, and create a new row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 self.retrieveTask = function(data, event) {
            if (event.type=="click") {
                var id = data.Id;
                var $taskSelected = event.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
                $.get("@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")", { id: id })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        var html = "";
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            html += "<tr><td>" +
                                "</td>" +
                                "<td>" +
                                "  <div >" +
                                + value.Type +
                                "</div> " +
                                "</td>" +
                                "<td>" +
                                " <div >" +
                                value.Id +
                                "</div> " +
                                "</td>" +
                               "</tr>";

                        });
                       $taskSelected.innerHTML=html;

                    }).fail(function() {
                        alert("error");
                    });
            };

        }
```

All I did was move `var html` outside of your `each` loop. This makes sure that all your previous HTML stays inside the variable, otherwise you are overwriting `html` each time you run through the loop (This is why you're only outputting the last one ;) ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer indeed it was wrong with the scope, by the way my worst error here was the structure of my table as Teemu says. I fix it  changed the structure of my table and add after the current row with    $(html).insertAfter($taskSelected). Thanks again.